# Implicit surface representation of a cube

Tags: geometry

Implicit representation is of the form f(x, y, z) = 0. For a sphere it is just $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2$.  I am wondering what is the equation for a cube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\max (|x|,|y|,|z| ) = 1$ for the unit cube.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for quick response!